# Parametrizing boundary for Stokes' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Evaluate the integral $\iint_S(\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot d\mathbf{S}$, where $S$ is the portion of the surface of a sphere defined by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $x + y + z \ge 1$, and where $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{r} \times (\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k}), \mathbf{r} = x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j} + z\mathbf{k}$.

Is the correct approach for this problem to use Stokes' Theorem and calculate $\int_C\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{s}$, where $C$ is the boundary of $S$? I tried doing this, but I had trouble parametrizing $C$. In particular, I plugged in $z = 1 - x - y$ into $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and was stuck when I had to parametrize the resulting region in the xy-plane. Where did I go wrong? What would I need to do differently if I had to solve this problem going the line integral route?

Comment: Not an answer to the parameterisation question but a different approach to the question altogether - instead of doing a line integral, you may convert the question to another surface integral. Namely, the surface $S_2$ which is the portion of the plane $x + y + z = 1$ within the unit sphere. Note that this surface also has $C$ as boundary and thus, another application of Stokes' will show that the integrals are equal. The calculations are easier here. (Remember to orient this correctly.)

Comment: The normal to the plane $x+y+z=1$ is $\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k}$.  Try rotating this to the $z$-axis, so it's easy to parameterize the intersection, then rotate back.  (I haven't done this, but it seems it ought to work.)  Aryaman's appraoch is probably better, though.

Comment: Unless, I am making a mistake $\nabla \times F = \nabla \times (x,y,z) \times (1,1,1) = (0,0,0)$  Furthermore, (if I indeed have made a basic mistake here)  since $\nabla \times F$ is always a divergence free field, you can integrate over the disk and you will get the same surface integral.

Comment: @DougM Hmm... I get $\operatorname{curl}\mathbf F=(-2,-2,-2)$. Maybe you computed $(\nabla\times(x,y,z))\times(1,1,1)$, which does vanish, instead of $\nabla\times((x,y,z)\times(1,1,1))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt you’re familiar with the parameterization in $\mathbb R^2$ of a circle with radius $r$ centered at $\mathbf c=(x_c,y_c)$ as $(x_c+r\cos t,y_c+r\sin t)$. We can rewrite this in vector form as $\mathbf c+(r\cos t)\mathbf e_1+(r\sin t)\mathbf e_2$. It should be fairly clear that we can use any pair of orthogonal unit vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ instead of the standard basis vectors $\mathbf e_1$ and $\mathbf e_2$. This amounts to changing the starting point on the circle of the parameterization and possibly reversing its orientation. Observe now that $\mathbf c+(r\cos t)\mathbf u+(r\sin t)\mathbf v$ works as a parameterization of a circle in an ambient space of any dimension $\ge2$.

In your problem, the circle lies on the plane $x+y+z=1$ with normal $\mathbf n=\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k$, which also happens to be the constant vector in the definition of $\mathbf F$. Its center is at $\frac13(\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k)$ and its radius can be found via the Pythagorean theorem to be $\sqrt{2/3}$. To complete the parameterization, we just need a pair of orthogonal unit vectors that are perpendicular to $\mathbf n$. An obvious choice is $\mathbf u = \frac1{\sqrt2}(\mathbf i-\mathbf j)$ and the other is then found by computing $\mathbf n\times\mathbf u$ and normalizing. The resulting parameterization of the circle is $$\frac13\left(\sin t+\sqrt3\cos t+ 1\right)\mathbf i + \frac13\left(\sin t-\sqrt3\cos t+1\right)\mathbf j + \frac13\left(1-2\sin t\right)\mathbf k.$$

You can save yourself a lot of work in computing $\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf s$ with the following observations:

- $\mathbf F$ is orthogonal to both $\mathbf n$ and $\mathbf r$, so along $C$ it is parallel to $\dot{\mathbf r}$, but points in the opposite direction. Thus, $\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf s = -\lVert\mathbf F\rVert \lVert\dot{\mathbf r}\rVert dt$.
- Along $C$, $\lVert\mathbf F\rVert = r\lVert\mathbf n\rVert$.
- $\lVert\dot{\mathbf r}\rVert = {2\pi r\over 2\pi} = r$.

It sounds like you tried something like solving $x+y+z=1$ for $z$ and then substituting into the equation of the sphere, which produces $x^2+xy+y^2-x-y=0$. Using standard methods such as setting the partial derivatives to zero, you can find that the center of this conic is at $\left(\frac13,\frac13\right)$. The symmetry of the quadratic part suggests a rotation through $\pi/2$: setting $x={x'+y'\over\sqrt2}+\frac13$ and $y={y'-x'\over\sqrt2}+\frac13$ reduces the equation to $\frac32x'^2+\frac92y'^2=1$. This ellipse can be parameterized as $\left(\frac{\sqrt2}3\cos t,\sqrt{\frac23}\sin t\right)$. If you work back through the transformations, you’ll end up with the same parameterization as above.

Comment: Can you explain how you got your second and third bullet points?

Comment: @Edufh I had a few typos there, now fixed. For the second point, $\lVert\mathbf F\rVert = \lVert\mathbf r\times\mathbf n\rVert = \lVert\mathbf r\rVert \lVert\mathbf n\rVert \lvert\sin\phi\rvert$, where $\phi$ is the angle between the two vectors. On $C$, this angle is constant, with $\lvert\sin\phi\rvert=r/\lVert\mathbf r\rVert$. For the third, $\lVert\dot{\mathbf r}\rVert$ is constant in this parameterization, so this is just speed = distance / time.